# Icon handle and resource ID

Tags: c, winapi, autoit

When an icon is loaded with the Windows API function LoadImage (from a file), is there a resource ID associated to it? If so, how to retrieve it?

Comment: no, there is no resource id associated with it

Comment: You've got that chicken before the egg, you have to supply the resource ID to LoadImage().

Comment: The icon ID serves as a lookup into the icon directory in the same way a path name serves as a lookup into the local file system. It is used to identify the source only, and once `LoadImage` returns an image, information about its source is discarded. The source is an input to `LoadImage`. If you need to persist the relation between image and source, you have to store it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you load a *file* instead of a *resource*, there will not be any resource ID associated with the returned `HANDLE`.  The file data is loaded into memory and a new temp image is created to represent it.  when you close the returned `HANDLE`, that temp image will be destroyed.

If you load a *resource* instead of a *file*, you have to tell `LoadImage()` the resource ID to load.  You cannot query an image `HANDLE` for its resource ID, but you would have had to already had the ID to begin with, so just pass it around alongside the loaded image as needed.

Comment: There's no resource ID to begin with, the icon is loaded with the flag **LR_LOADFROMFILE**.

Comment: @fjkadshfja I'm aware of that. I stated as much in the first half of my answer.